# Cómo resuelvo este npm ERR con gyp, stack Error?

Tags: nodejs, visual-studio, vscode

Recientemente emigré a Windows 10 (Compré un nuevo equipo) y ha sido un gran rollazo intentar instalar en mi caso mariadb, el mismo error  me había sucedido antes en windows 7 pero no obstante dicho error se había solucionado instalando las herramientas de VS en windows junto a python y node-gyp.

No obstante, NADA FUNCIONA EN WINDOWS 10 y hago énfasis en ello debido a que en verdad lo he intentado de todo y nada funciona, ya instalé las librerías correspondientes mencionadas anteriormente y ahora me está tirando este error el cual llevo semanas intentando solucionar sin problema alguno, empiezo a temerme el hecho de tener que regresar a windows 7 al no encontrar soluciones al respecto:

```
    gyp ERR! build error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1      
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Express\Documents\GitHub\scutes\node_modules\mariasql
    gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! mariasql@0.2.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the mariasql@0.2.6 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\Express\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-06T14_13_45_854Z-debug.log
```

¿Alguien tendrá alguna idea de que podria estar saliendo mal? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Estás instalando un paquete que al parecer no tiene mucho mantenimiento: [`mariasql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariasql), entre las incidencias abiertas que tiene dicho paquete se encuentra [esta](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql/issues/207), la cual sugiere que mejor instales [`mariadb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mariadb). Este último paquete si que ha sido actualizado y tiene mayor soporte. Saludos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!